# Using Shapely on AWS Lambda with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, shapely

I am trying to set up a skill using Shapely on Lambda.  I got the error

```
module initialization error: Could not find lib geos_c or load any of its variants ['libgeos_c.so.1', 'libgeos_c.so'].
```

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190029/setting-up-shapely-on-aws-lambda-python-functions) for Python 2.7. I can't use the [lambda-packs by ryfeus](https://github.com/ryfeus/lambda-packs) cause I'm on Python 3.6, but I figured the EC2 approach described by [Graeme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5577416/graeme) should work.

So I started up an EC2 instance using the Public Amazon Linux AMI version from the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html)

I then ran these commands

```
$ sudo yum -y update
$ sudo yum -y install python36 python36-virtualenv python36-pip
$ mkdir ~/forlambda
$ cd ~/forlambda
$ virtualenv -p python3 venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

and then installed Shapely and a few other packages I needed.

```
$ sudo yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
$ pip install python-dateutil
$ pip install shapely 
$ pip install pyproj 
$ pip install pyshp
```

I then ran my skill (on the EC2 instance), and it works!  So then I copied the files at venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages, plus the myskill.py and zipped them up, uploaded to Lambda, and still get the geos_c error as shown above :(

I have been able to upload a scaled-down version of my skill (minus Shapely, but including other packages that don't come with Lambda) and it works on Lambda, so I don't think it's an error on how I am zipping or uploading.

Am I missing something?  Does it make a difference that the Development Tools were installed using "sudo yum install" instead of "pip install"?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the pip install of Shapely and Pyproj didn't end up in the virtualenv site-packages.  From a fresh EC2 instance, I ran these commands:

```
$ sudo yum -y update
$ sudo yum -y install python36 python36-virtualenv python36-pip
$ mkdir ~/forlambda
$ cd ~/forlambda
$ virtualenv -p python3 venv
$ source venv/bin/activate

(venv) $ sudo yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
(venv) $ pip install python-dateutil
(venv) $ pip install shapely -t ~/forlambda/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
(venv) $ pip install pyproj -t ~/forlambda/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
(venv) $ pip install pyshp
```

and then zipped up all the contents of site-packages/ plus myskill.py, uploaded to Lambda, and it worked.